# Как сделать чтобы при открытии второй картинки первая закрывалась? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pil

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, IntVar
from PIL import Image
root = Tk()
root.title("GUI на Python")
root.geometry("300x250")

count = IntVar()
def on_click():
    count.set(count.get() + 1)
    return commend1() if count.get() % 2 else commend2()

def commend1():
    img = Image.open(r'qr.png')
    img.show()

def commend2():
    img = Image.open(r'2.jpg')
    img.show()

btn = Button(root,  command=on_click)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Использовать не `img.show()`, а виджет для отображения картинок из `tkinter`

Answer (score 2):

Не использовать `img.show()`, т.к. в этом случае будет использовать стандартное приложение для просмотра картинок, а его контролировать будет сложно, вообще, при вызове этой команды будет вызван:

1. `ImageShow.show` из `PIL.Image.py`
2. В `ImageShow.show` будет поиск подходящего просмотрщика из переменной-списка модуля `_viewers`, [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/ef59657518b328cf2ce459a41dbee0a52a0b0766/pil_pillow__examples/get_viewers.py#L11):

   ```
   from PIL.ImageShow import _viewers
   print(_viewers)
   # [<PIL.ImageShow.WindowsViewer object at 0x0000019E67221550>]
   ```
3. А узнать что происходит для вызова просмотрщика, можно так:

   ```
   print(_viewers[0].get_command('123.png'))
   # start "Pillow" /WAIT "123.png" && ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL && del /f "123.png"
   ```

##### Поэтому решением будет, считаю, размещение картинок на виджете окна

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/cbb495a188f728cbef19911fdfd13b3a6af5b7c0/tkinter_examples/button__change_button_icon_on_click/main__next_image_generator__using__itertools_cycle.py)

```
import itertools
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')


CYCLED_IMAGES = itertools.cycle([
    tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/ok.png"),
    tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/no.png"),
    tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/help.png"),
])


def get_next_image() -> tk.PhotoImage:
    return next(CYCLED_IMAGES)


def _on_button_click():
    panel.config(image=get_next_image())


panel = tk.Label(root, image=get_next_image())
panel.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="ClickMe!")
button.config(command=_on_button_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**PS.**

Цикличное получение картинок, как слайд шоу, сделано на основе [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1334841/201445)

Comment: Не работает. Выдает ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_app'

Comment: @AlexChorniy, т.е. вы скопировали мой код, в `CYCLED_IMAGES` указали актуальные пути к картинкам, запустили код и получили такую ошибку? :) Или попробовали мой код адаптировать к своему и получили ошибку? В любом случае, покажите трассу стека ошибки, т.к. непонятно в каком моменте упало и откуда идет попытка импорта `_app`

Comment: @AlexChorniy, разобрались с ошибкой? :) Отметьте и примите мой ответ, если вам он помог :)

Answer (score 0):

Если всё же хочется использовать img.show(), то могу предложить получать список всех процессов, запущенных в просмотрщике картинок, перед открытием новой картинки и сразу после открытия. Через разницу этих величин определять номер процесса, вызванного последним img.show() и затем завершать его при очередном нажатии кнопки.

Используется time.sleep(0.01) - время, достаточное для запуска просмотрщика и появления его pid в списке процессов системы.

Это решение позволит, например, запустить несколько таких пайтоновских скриптов одновременно, и при этом при нажатии кнопки в одном скрипте не закрывать картинки открытые в другом скрипте:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, IntVar
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageShow import _viewers
import psutil
import time
    
root = Tk()
root.title("GUI на Python")
root.geometry("300x250")

def get_viewers():
    viewers = [_viewer.get_command_ex('')[0] for _viewer in _viewers]
    pids = []
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() in viewers:
            pids.append(proc.pid)
    return pids

def kill_viewer(pid):
    psutil.Process(pid).terminate()

active_viewer = None
count = IntVar()
def on_click():
    global active_viewer
    if active_viewer:
        kill_viewer(active_viewer)
    count.set(count.get() + 1)
    viewers_before_exec = get_viewers()
    commend1() if count.get() % 2 else commend2()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    active_viewer = list(set(get_viewers()) - set(viewers_before_exec))[0]

def commend1():
    img = Image.open(r'qr.png')
    img.show()

def commend2():
    img = Image.open(r'2.jpeg')
    img.show()

btn = Button(root, command=on_click)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Если же нет риска закрытия сторонних просмотрщиков, то можно просто добавить к вашему исходному коду функции on_click() kill_all_viewers() для завершения вообще всех просмотрщиков, которые могут быть использованы PIL. В случае работы только одного подобного скрипта этого будет достаточно:

```
def kill_all_viewers():
    viewers = [_viewer.get_command_ex('')[0] for _viewer in _viewers]
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() in viewers:
            proc.terminate()

count = IntVar()
def on_click():
    kill_all_viewers()
    count.set(count.get() + 1)
    return commend1() if count.get() % 2 else commend2()
```